# How to describe query parameters in DRF Docs?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework v3.9 built-in interactive documentation.
I have a url need query parameters for get.
such as:
 `../jobs/?order_choice=0&city=1&region=0`
But i don't know how to documenting it in interactive documentation.

I use `method:` to add parameters:
such as:

```py
class JobListView(APIView):
    """
    get:
    - order_choices
    - city
    - region
    - job_type
    """
```

but it print in one line

```
- order_choices - city - region - job_type
```

it's my parameters/

```py
    params_data = {
        'city': request.query_params.get('city', None),
        'region': request.query_params.get('region', None),
        'job_type': request.query_params.get('job_type', None),
        'status': 1,
    }
```

I want to know how to documenting it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below ...

```
class PackageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
"""
** Query Parameters **

    `page` - get data of a particular page.

    `page_size` - change total objects in a page (default=20).

** Filter Parameters **

    `status` - `1/2`

** Search Parameters **

    `name` - `search by package name`

** Ordering Parameters **

    `name`

    `created_at`

    `updated_at`

** Default Ordering **

    `-created_at`

`Method Allowed`

    `GET -` `Lists all the Packages of a facility/company.`

    `POST -` `Creates Package for a facility.`

    `PUT -` `Updates a Package.`

    `DELETE -` `deletes a Package.`

`POST/Create, PUT/Update`

    {
        "name": "package one",
        "description": "package one",
        "status": 1    // 1- Active, 2-Inactive
    }
"""
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I copied all the comments. It still shows up in one line.